# Why there is right margin in Compass CSS Blueprint?

Tags: css, blueprint-css, css-frameworks, compass-sass

I've use the compass CSS with blueprint for sometimes. I notice there's a right margin with every column in compass CSS.

Is it required? how can I remove it?

Because sometimes it's quite annoying and mess with my design plan.

```
#hc, #fc {
    @include column($blueprint-grid-columns);
}
```

This cause #hc to have a right margin.

Comment: I am not sure, It's the version integrated with compass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can just set the column margins via the config variable:

```
 $blueprint-grid-margin: 10px
```

See the reference:
http://compass-style.org/reference/blueprint/grid/#const-blueprint-grid-margin